# Do wireless KVM switches exist? (wireless plugging to PCs, not peripherals)

Tags: usb, kvm-switch, wireless-keyboard, wireless-mouse

I always have from 2 to 5 PCs for repair on my room, they come in and out very quickly. I use KVM solutions for working with them, but I'd like to avoid constantly plugging and unplugging so many wires, and also avoid having all of them - the wires - around, because they tend to insanely cross between themselves.

I'd love to find a KVM switch which allows devices to be connected to a wireless USB dongle, so they see a mouse and a keyboard connected. I only aim to avoid wires for the keyboard and the mouse this way, I assume video connection will still be mandatory, but it's worth achieving the USB part. If the solution achieved also wireless video, it would be wonderfull.

I've googled for days and I've only found people aiming to connect wireless keyboards to the switch, but I want to connect the KVM to the computers wirelessly.

This image from [this Quora post](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-KVM-switch-that-uses-Bluetooth) is very nice, take a look at Computer D.
[image: KVM bluetooth example]

An example of what I am NOT looking for is [this product](http://www.atlona.com/Atlona-AT-PCLINK-Wireless-DVI-with-Stereo-Audio-and-Dual-USB-KVM-Extender.html). It achieves wireless transmission of input devices and even video, but only plugs via USB and needs a software installed on the computer being controlled. I want the receiver/transmitter dongle part to phisically connect to all the PC inputs and to virtualize the hardware interface.

Lots of thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use bluetooth for that. It won't work in BIOS, you will need to pair the devices etc. I'd recommend using DVI+USB, a KVM will allow you to do this. You can even put a hub between each computer and the KVM, so you can connect a USB NIC.

Comment: It doesn't need to work in that way. If you buy a bluetooth keyboard it comes with a dongle which is set to automatically pair to the keyboard instantly and indeed works for booting into BIOS. If someone builds this device, the dongles which will come with it will communicate with the switch to see which will receive input, and all of them will work as a generic HID device for the PC side

Comment: That's not bluetooth, it'433 mhz for example...

Comment: Oh god.. are you telling me that generally wireless keyboards/mices out in the market are not using bluetooth?

Comment: Yes, mostly it's proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [IOGEAR GKM611B Bluetooth Multimedia Keyboard with Touchpad](http://www.shopiogear.com/DRHM/store?Action=pd&SiteID=iogear&Locale=en_US&Env=BASE&productID=225763700)
It allows up to 6 Bluetooth devices at once.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DavidPostill It's a link to an online shop—what exactly should be included here?

Comment: @DavidPostill I've given the make, model number, description of what the device is, and what it does that make it an answer to the question asked. I've even thrown in the embedded link as a bonus :) I'm not really sure what else you want me to add... Even if the link becomes obsolete, the rest of the information will remain valid.

Comment: Not a direct hardware interface simulator for the PC side, but a real bluetooth keyboard with multiclient. It's not exactly what I am looking for but it's a good product to know, thank you!!